# make enter key act as Tab key on Textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to make <kbd>Enter</kbd> key act as <kbd>Tab</kbd> key 
one text Box in asp.net using jQuery?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         var inputs = $(':input').keypress(function (e) {
             if (e.which == 13) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(this) + 1);
                 if (nextInput) {
                     nextInput.focus();
                 }
             }
         });

     });                                    
 </script>     
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("input").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("input").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: `return false = event.stopPropagation() + event.preventDefault()`